# starting with the MEAN stack, just grunted

Tags: node.js, pug, mean-stack

So, I'm getting MEAN. Everything is installed. I have some issues, though, and I'm hoping for a bit of guidance on how to read these error logs. I'm coming from Rails, for reference.

First things first, following along with http://mean.io/, `npm install` had some issues, but updating and clearing cache took care of it. Now I'm grunting. First thing I get is:

```
Express app started on port 3000

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
at null.<anonymous>(D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:540:74)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
at null.<anonymous> (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:140:15)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:478:10)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:441:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
22 Dec 21:03:14 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So, I took a guess and thought maybe I had to manually start mongo? `mongod` then in a new console, `grunt`. `Express app started on port 3000`!! Woot. Upon visiting `http://localhost:3000/`, I get this monstrosity:

```
Error: D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\app\views\layouts\default.jade:1 > 1| !!! 5 2| html(lang='en', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', xmlns:fb='https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml', itemscope='itemscope', itemtype='http://schema.org/Product') 3| include ../includes/head 4| body `!!!` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype` at Object.Lexer.doctype (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:246:13) at Object.Lexer.next (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:812:15) at Object.Lexer.lookahead (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:111:46) at Parser.lookahead (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:109:23) at Parser.peek (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:86:17) at Parser.parse (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:124:26) at Parser.parse (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:138:24) at parse (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:95:62) at Object.exports.compile (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:152:9) at Object.exports.render (D:\Dropbox\Apps\mean_projects\first\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:256:15)
```

So, I take it the first or second thing is the issue, and the rest just trickles down to the parent elements, right? Somethings not right in my `layouts/default.jade` file. Everything is stock here, I haven't made any edits. Jade looks a lot like HAML... I think I'm going to like this!

Should I be having to start `mongod` manually? And to that extent, shouldn't that be starting somewhere in my project? I'm a bit confused on that. I'm actually jumping into this whole MEAN thing because I want to learn mongo and NoSQL, so I definitely need to get that squared away.

So, I'd like to get this up and running. Any other tips and tricks you can throw at me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to start Mongo manually?  You want to restart it every time you restart your app?  For what it's worth, I personally cannot stand Jade.  Its parsers do weird things, and never seem to work properly for me.  Then again, I also hate HAML... it's a matter of opinion.  If I had advice for you, it would be to **not** start off by installing every single possible thing you can, but to understand what exactly each component is first.

Comment: I'm just starting with what's at mean.io. It didn't mention anything about having to start mongo manually, so I found it odd. I just want to get 'everything' running and then I'll start dissecting.

Comment: @Mallanaga did you solve it ? i have the same kind of problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915513/error-when-starting-the-server-with-grunt-or-node-server

Comment: it was a jade version. so in `package.json` in dependencies, jade was at latest... i had to change that to 0.35 then ran `npm update` to get it moving.

Comment: @Mallanaga i tried to put jade version to 0.35, but it doesn't change anything. On the other side it's working if I run `mongod`, before to run `grunt`. do you need to do that too ?

Comment: did you `npm update` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the mean.io repo...
No need for a manual change anymore ..
https://github.com/linnovate/mean/pull/198

Answer (score 7):

Latest version of Jade has a new doctype syntax.
As it's written in Error message, you had to change in **default.jade** line with `!!!` to `doctype`, i.e.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
```

Comment: That's annoying, even though it makes sense why they did that. Thanks for the post.

Comment: We switched jade to swig to avoid the cryptic synatax and to deliver something much closer to HTML markeup for the server side templating