# error when starting the server with grunt or node server

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, mean-stack

I am trying to use the mean stack as described here : http://mean.io/

after install, when making "grunt", there is an error :

```
debugger listening on port 5858
4 Jan 01:47:40 - [nodemon] reading ignore list
Express app started on port 3000

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/mean/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/mean/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mean/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
4 Jan 01:47:40 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried the troubleshooting as specified on the site : Updating Grunt, bower and cleaning npm and bower caches worked well. but updating npm gives an error too:

```
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/npm not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

This looks like a [conflict between homebrew and npm](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22408). 
but anyway i have version 1.3.21 installed.

There is the same error when i am trying `node server`.

do you have an idea on what i can do to make the server work ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It may be too easy, but seems like your MongoDB server is not actually running. After having installed Mongo (on your Mac, I assume?), you have to open a Terminal window/tab, run `mongod` and leave it running (or use `screen`, etc.). You can try to access MongoDB CLI by typing `mongo` to make sure the server is running.

Comment: thanks this is working ! They should add this in then mean.io documentation. Do I have to run `mongod` before running `grunt`everytime ?

Comment: Mongo must be running all the time you want your stack to be up. Since 'M' in MEAN means Mongo, your site is using MongoDB constantly, so the Mongo server must be up all the time during development, and in production you'll probably have a `mongod` service on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

@desgnl: if you don't want to run mongod command everytime you are running the grunt, you can always use third party services like MongoDB Hosting: Database-as-a-Service by MongoLab https://mongolab.com  Hope this helps too!